# 3D Touch Quick Actions inside iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3dtouch

I am developing a mobile app that supports 3D Touch. I would like to implement a Quick Action menu for some controls inside app, like Contacts app has. I attach a screenshot for better understanding.

[image: Contacts 3D Touch]

Answer (score 0):

For adding these quick actions inside app you can implement `Peek and Pop` functionality in your app.

For integrating `Peek and Pop` you can follow this tutplus tutorial.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-an-introduction-to-3d-touch--cms-25115

Hope, it helps

Answer (score -1):

You can try my own library [**ActionsList**](https://github.com/LowKostKustomz/ActionsList) which has the same look and feel as Apple's Quick Actions menu.

It **has not 3D Touch support yet**, but it can help you with presenting the same actions list as on the provider screenshot.

**First you should create list.**

If you want to present it from `UIButton`, `UIBarButtonItem` of `UITabBarItem` there is built-in methods for creating list:

```
// element is UIButton, UIBarButtonItem or UITabBarItem
let list = element.createActionsList()
```

Otherwise you should use `ActionsListModel` structure:

```
let list = ActionsListModel(senderView: viewThatInitiatedListPresenting,
                            sourceView: viewToPresentListFrom,
                            delegate: listDelegate)
```

**Then add actions to the list**

```
list.add(action: ActionsListDefaultButtonModel(localizedTitle: "Create Alarm", 
                 image: UIImage(named: "Alarm clock"),
                 action: { action in
                     // You can use action's list property to control it

                     // - To dismiss
                     action.list?.dismiss()

                     // - To update action appearance
                     action.appearance.//anything
                     // Do not forget to reload actions to apply changes
                     action.list?.reloadActions()
          }))
```

**After that you can present list**

```
list.present()

// Save list or it will be deallocated and not reachable outside of the scope it was created in
self.list = list
```

[image: ActionsListExample app]